# How to maintain Session with putty?

Tags: unix, session-timeout, putty

I found that when I use putty for our UNIX server connection, it gets time out message after certain time period. Every time I open putty window which is already connected, it it has been idle for more that say 30 minutes, it gets time out and I have to login again to new putty session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found one simple solution for the putty to resolve the "Idle Session Timeout", which overcomes logging again and again to Unix box Putty Sessions. This solution ensures that even if the login remained Idle for a longer time the session does not get killed till exit is explicitly performed.

In Putty Login Screen, Inside Category goTo Connections and change the value for "seconds between keepalives" to a positive number greater than 0. most probably 2 to keep the session alive. This keeps the session alive for even many days.

Comment: 2 seconds is massively overkill. My sessions seem to time out after 5 minutes, so I've set my keep-alive to 60 seconds.

Comment: The fact is, I was not aware the measure of value '2'. Thanks for letting me know that it is in seconds.